# AttributeError: 'RootLogger' object has no attribute 'setlevel'. Did you mean: 'setLevel'? how to use this function in other functions

Tags: python, logging

I have a function logger iam getting an attribute error   while running and also i need to understand how to use this function in any other functions and how it will work

```
def logger():
    logger=logging.getLogger()
    logger.setlevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter=logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(clientip)-15s %(user)-8s %(message)s')
    handler=logging.streamhandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setlevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain what your question is? It's not very obvious since the error statement tells you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I need to understand the above  logger function  what it does

Comment: The 'above logger function' is documented. What part of the documentation for it did you have difficulty with?